# How can two instances of firebase run on a single machine for testing multiplayer builds in Unity?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore

I'm getting really frustrated with Firebase devs who close my questions just because they don't contain minimum reproducible code. This is a valid question and there are useful answers out there.

My Firebase app works in the editor, and it works in build, but when I try to run both at the same time, the second instance crashes once the first Firebase command is invoked (firestore snapshot).

I suspect that I may need to create a firebase instance with a different name, but I'm not sure how. Right now the two instances both use Firebase.DefaultInstance.

The crash gives no errors, and the editor logs show everything runs fine until

```
Query q = db.Collection("matches").OrderByDescending("players");
QuerySnapshot snapSht = await q.GetSnapshotAsync();
```

How do I run a second Unity-Firebase instance on a single local machine for multiplayer testing?

Steps to reproduce problem:

1. Install and set up firebase in Unity per the documentation
2. Initialize the app and fetch a snapshot from Firestore
3. Build and run the app
4. While build is running, press play in Unity Editor. Once the snapshot code runs, Unity will crash.
5. If Editor is run first, the build will be the one to crash

Comment: Minimum reproducible code is required on Stack Overflow, as are specific debugging details.  That's why your question keeps getting closed.  I suggest improving your answer by providing enough detail that would allow anyone to easily duplicate the situation you describe.

Comment: You have to use a virtual machine as firebase as a Device ID checker so u can only run one device to prevent overuse/spam/farming etc

Comment: @DougStevenson But how can I provide minimum reproducible code when the problem is simply having two instances of the code running? MRC isn't applicable in this instance.

Comment: You could provide the exact series of steps you follow to cause the problem.  Anyone should be able to follow along with what you show, and experience the same result.

Comment: I got it to work like this:
```
AppOptions options = new AppOptions();
options.ApiKey = "...";
options.AppId = "...";
options.DatabaseUrl = new System.Uri("...");
options.ProjectId = "...";
options.StorageBucket = "...";

app = FirebaseApp.Create(options,  Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
_db = FirebaseFirestore.GetInstance(_app);
```

Comment: Btw: The linked duplicate is not there anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have two app instances, you'll have to initialize at least one [`FirebaseApp` instance](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/firebase-app) yourself, by [passing in the necessary configuration data in `AppOptions`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/firebase-app#class_firebase_1_1_firebase_app_1aaeb3418d9c118fcb63a409ee05a5e4aa).

You can get the configuration data from the Firebase console, or from the configuration file for the secondary (`google-services.json` or `google-service.info.plist`). app config file.

Comment: Are you recommending to create a second app for the project as described in [Configure Multiple Projects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects)?

Comment: I think you're being needlessly obtuse. I appreciate your response but I don't appreciate you closing my questions without giving them a chance to get more answers. There is plenty of information in my post. I'm forced to make duplicates because you close my questions and they don't get reopened.

Comment: I didn't close your question. Insulting people who are trying to help you is not a great way to ensure we'll keep trying though. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯